# str.replace with a variable

Tags: python, variables, replace

This is probably a simple fix, but having a little trouble getting my head around it; I'm reading lines from a different script, and want to replace a line with a variable, however it replaces it with `box1` instead of the values `55, 55.7`

```
box1 = 55, 55.7
box2 = -9, -7

with open('parttest', 'r') as file :
    filedata = file.read()

filedata = filedata.replace('box_lat', 'box1')
filedata = filedata.replace('box_lon', 'box2')

with open('buildtest', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: Anything within (single or double) quotes is a string in Python

Comment: @sam2090 or triple or sextuple quotes! `"""these too""" '''and these!'''`

Comment: @AdamSmith Yeah. Multiline string in case future readers dont know what they are called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently are replacing those values with the literal name of the variable. If you want it to use the values that those variable names refer to, omit the quotes.

Next, you'll have to turn those variables into strings, because I suspect that the reason you used quotes in the first place was because you got an error without them, as well. This is because `replace` takes only strings, and your variables are `tuple`s. To fix this, cast the variable to a string.

```
filedata = filedata.replace('box_lat', str(box1))
```

If you don't want to keep the parentheses that appear in a string representation of a `tuple`, you can strip them off:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('box_lat', str(box1).strip('()'))
```

Comment: `str(box1)` is going to give the string representation of a tuple not `55, 55.7`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - If the parentheses are undesired, we can use `str(box1).strip('()')`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace with the value of the variable box1 you need to remove the quotes surrounding it. Try:

```
box1 = "55, 55.7"
box2 = "-9, -7"
filedata = filedata.replace('box_lat', box1)
filedata = filedata.replace('box_lon', box2)
```

Quotes will replace with the text enclosed; whereas, a variable name should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As @tigerhawk and @sam said if you enter something in quotes it means the literal thing you typed in the quotes so try removing the quotes around 'box 1'