# Python How to replace specific string in brackets?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I wanna replace the specific string in bracket accordingly. The string is not created by myself, so I cannot control the format of the string. What I have are the `example_str`  and the `price` and I want to replace `[apple_price]` by the `apple_price` defined. Here is the example.

```
apple_price = 50
orange_price = 40
example_str = "Apple costs $ [apple_price] and Orange costs $ [orange_price]"

Expected Output: "Apple costs $ 50 and Orange costs $ 40"
```

I tried to replace it by `re`, but it replaced same string to all bracket .

```
re.sub("[\[].*?[\)\]]", apple_price , example_str )
```

Comment: Do you create the string elsewhere or can you just create a format string?

Comment: @Sayse I cannot control the format of the string. I need to replace the [String] to the Integer

Comment: It is hightly recommended to never use built-in `str`as name.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg thanks for your reminder. Actually, its not the real case. just example. cheers

Comment: Sometimes  'just example' code can end up in actual code :-) and this may be relevant: 'Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.sub` accepts a callable as replacement to dynamically construct the replacement string. The argument to the callable is a `re.Match` object.

The pattern is modified to capture the variable name. For non-existing variable, no substitution is performed, ie. `Match.group(0)` is returned.

```py
import re

text = "Apple costs $ [apple_price] and Orange costs $ [orange_price] $ [does_not_exist]"

variables = {
    'apple_price': 50,
    'orange_price': 40,
}

print(re.sub(
    r"[\[](.*?)[\)\]]",
    lambda m: str(variables.get(m.group(1), m.group(0))),
    text,
))
```

Output:

```
Apple costs $ 50 and Orange costs $ 40 $ [does_not_exist]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format strings`. How format strings work is you add '`{}`' brackets to the string, and using the `format` function, we add variable in that order. They will be added to where the brackets lie.

So in your case:

```
apple_price = 50
orange_price = 40
str = "Apple costs $ {} and Orange costs $ {}"
print(str.format(apple_price, orange_price))
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my description is not clear. I cannot control the format of the string.

Comment: Ah Ok. Please add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can also use string replace methods along with formatting:

```
apple_price = 50
orange_price = 40
str = "Apple costs $[apple_price] and Orange costs $[orange_price]"

result = str.replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}').replace('apple_price','').replace('orange_price','')

print(result.format(apple_price, orange_price))
# Apple costs $50 and Orange costs $40
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python use format .

```
apple_price = 50
orange_price = 40
example_str = f"Apple costs $ {apple_price} and Orange costs $ {orange_price}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are overcomplicating things by trying to use the `re` module. Simply using the builtin `str.replace` method should be sufficient in your case unless I missed some requirement.

```py
apple_price = 50
orange_price = 40
example_str = "Apple costs $ [apple_price] and Orange costs $ [orange_price]"

replaced = example_str.replace("[apple_price]", str(apple_price)).replace("[orange_price]", str(orange_price))

print(replaced)
```

This will replace all occurences of `[apple_price]` and `[orange_price]` with their respective values and give the following output:

> Apple costs $ 50 and Orange costs $ 40

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use python reserved names as the variable names. In this case, you are using `str` as your variable name which is reserved for the `string` type in python.

Having said that, here is a simple code that uses [str.replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

```
apple_price = 50
orange_price = 40

fruits_price = "Apple costs $ [apple_price] and Orange costs $ [orange_price]"
fruits_price = fruits_price.replace("[apple_price]",str(apple_price)).replace("[orange_price]",str(orange_price))
print(fruits_price)
```

Output:

```
Apple costs $ 50 and Orange costs $ 40
```

All you have to do is to pass your variable as a string. To know more [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113076/str-replace-with-a-variable)